# manage users in my Windows & Web application Logic

Tags: c#, asp.net, business-logic

How to be a good way to manage users in my Windows & Web application? Is there an open Source project do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manage your users and their roles in active directory.  Perform authentication and authorization in your app (using, for example, membership and role providers).